# How to disable posting UIKeyboardWillShowNotification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, uitextfield

My custom `UITextField` has different inputViews. So when the inputView is an ordinary keyboard i want to show a toolbar and i use `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`. But when its inputView is say `UIDatePicker` i don't need that notification and it's actually not relevant cause no keyboards will be shown. But still this notification happens to be issued. Is it possible to disable it somehow?

Comment: Why would you see a keyboard appear if you change the value of your date picker and programmatically set your custom text field's text property ?

Answer (score 0):

You can unregister your object so that it does not receive the notification. You register it again when the input view changes.

Comment: I don't think you can tell the system not to post it. You can only choose not to receive it.